# Configuring datasources at runtime with Camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

I did setup a very simple route in Apache Camel where a query is sent to a JDBC component to execute. I got the Camel project up and running.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to send dataSource1's database connection parameters in a RabbitMQ message's header. By connection parameters I mean driverClassName, url, username, password. The client of my app would enter all those parameters to decide what database to connect to. I will probably use routing slip depending on what driverClassName user has specified but that's a different thing.

Please note that in this example here I put the SQL statement in a file to make it simpler. How can I accomplish that?

Here's my Camel Context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

  <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:route>
      <camel:from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
      <camel:to uri="jdbc:dataSource1"/>
      <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
      <camel:log message="${body}"/>
    </camel:route>
  </camel:camelContext>

  <bean id="dataSource1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

And Maven project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.mycompany</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Spring Route</name>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.26</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Jdbc -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
          <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: With connection parameters you mean the user name and password?

Comment: Thanks for viewing my question Ralf. By connection parameters I mean driverClassName, url, username, password. I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource is a Spring bean. Create a bean of your own and have Spring inject the datasource. You can then [plug](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) that bean into your route before the JDBC step and use the exchange headers, which should contain the JMS headers, to update the properties of the datasource.

However, I think this design approach is asking for trouble:

- If you ever wanted to use a pooled data source (and you should), then you need to reset the pool of connections which is expensive
- You need to synchronize the state modifications of the (singleton) data source as it is not threadsafe in that respect and with Camel you are working in a multi-threaded framework
- You are sending user names and passwords for your DBs around the place and you should protect that information while it is in transit

There is probably more...

Comment: See, what I'm asking above is a very oversimplified version of what I'm trying to create. Thus solving the first problem and moving to next. Eventually what I have in mind is sending a "key" in transit to a connection string value that's defined in the database. I'll then keep a Set with those "keys" fetched in memory. As I said, first problem is how to define a datasource for the first load and inject in in camel-jdbc component. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a few years later. Buy I achieved this using AbstractRoutingDataSource which allows to change the data source dynamically (you do not need to reset the connection pool or the route)

Reference Link:
https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/